# global php variables not saving after redirect

Tags: php, redirect, drupal, global-variables

I am using a custom module in drupal. where in a function I have used 
`$GLOBALS['dataCapsue'] = array("some", "data", "here");` 
And then did a drupal_goto redirect to another url of my custom module. When i re declare global variable as 
`global $dataCapsule;`
 in another function. It returns **NULL**. What may be the cause of this issue. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a `$_SESSION['dataCapsue'] = array("some", "data", "here");`

like @Lorenz Meyer, Lorenz Meyer is correct, In drupal or others you need to use a session between requests ..

Answer (score 6):

Global variables are not persistent between http requests, like a redirect. You have to use a session to store this data between requests.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `$_SESSION` variable or a browser cookie to get the stored data on the other site.